# to create an android app for tv

Tags: android

I have worked on developing an android app for mobile platform in past. Now I need to create an android app for the the TV platform. I am new to the TV part . Any useful links/information would help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create applications for Google TV yet.

When this becomes possible, there will be plenty of useful links/information at that time.

Sorry!

Comment: ok..i think i got it wrong..i actually need to work on - a tv remote would be acting as an input device which would handle the events through Android OS.Basically need to write event handlers for them in android.The screens would need to be developed for some functionality on the TV screens.Any links on that?

Comment: @MadScientist: I am not aware of many Android devices offering IR capability, which is what a TV remote uses. I would recommend that you delete this question and start a new one, where you completely describe what it is you are trying to accomplish.